# Retain callback between rerenders

Tags: reactjs

I'm building an app with guarded actions and would like to achieve the following flow:

- anonymous user tries to run guarded action (e.g. play video - essentially modify React state)
- login modal pops up without any redirects
- user fills in the credentials and hits login button
- any kind of loader shows up (and replaces the previous app tree) and stays on the screen as long as user is being logged in
- once logged in, loader disappears and the authenticated app renders
- video starts playing, because the app knows the action user wanted to take

I haven't found a way to do that, because replacing the old app tree with loader and then putting it back on the screen makes the action run on an already unmnounted component.

I'm using a `<UserProvider>` component that wraps the whole tree to provide it with `authenticated` state.

Codesandbox to illustrate the issue:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-context-callback-l9xe9?file=/src/App.js

```
const MyContext = React.createContext();

const MyProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [auth, setAuth] = React.useState(false);
  const [reset, setReset] = React.useState(false);
  const [callback, setCallback] = React.useState(null);
  const guard = (cb) => {
    auth ? cb() : setCallback(() => cb);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (auth) {
      setReset(true);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setReset(false);
      }, 1000);
    }
  }, [auth]);

  if (reset) {
    return <p style={{ color: "red" }}>I pretend I'm logging you in</p>;
  }

  return (
    <MyContext.Provider
      value={{
        setAuth,
        auth,
        callback,
        setCallback,
        guard
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
};

const Child = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const mounted = React.useRef(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    mounted.current = true;

    return () => {
      mounted.current = false;
    };
  }, []);
  const myCallback = () => {
    setCount((cnt) => cnt + 1);
  };
  const { auth, setAuth, guard, callback, setCallback } = React.useContext(
    MyContext
  );

  return (
    <div>
      logged in: {`${auth}`}
      <br />
      count: {count}
      <br />
      {callback && (
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setAuth(true);
            callback();
            setCallback(null);
          }}
        >
          pretend login
        </button>
      )}
      <button onClick={() => guard(myCallback)}>
        increment (when authenticated)
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Is that even possible?

Comment: With current logic, you can't, you must lift the state up.

Answer (score 0):

That's a use case for [lifting the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper), you can't preserve the state after the component unmounts (Of course you can try reading from local storage but it's essentially the same logic as lifting the state).

Therefore lift the `count` state (to `App` or to the provider itself):

```
export default function App() {
  const state = React.useState(0);
  ...
```

[image: Edit react-context-callback (forked)]

Comment: Thanks for the idea, gave it a try and it works - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-context-callback-forked-fivtc?file=/src/App.js. However, this works for this very simple use case. I can't imagine doing this for every action I need to guard inside the real app - I think that would bring issues with prop drilling etc.

Imagine you need to guard different actions in different components with various levels of nesting inside the app. How would one implement that?

Comment: The provider can hold a state for all auth components (NOT RECOMMENDED), it knows if they are mounted or not. The components themself can be initilizaed accordingly. But, you already passing the `auth` boolean, the component can initialize itself like in this case (must start from count=1).

Comment: You are aware that the components **not really guarded**? In real-life scenarios you suppose to use guarded routes.

Comment: We nee to guard both routes and actions. Anonymous users might see the routes with some actions restricted (like you can't play the video until you login, yet you can see the movie detail page). Once you want to start playing, you face the login modal.

Comment: Regarding the previous comment, I could initialize the guarded components with some kind of `onAuthenticatedMountCallback` prop, that would work.

Since I'm rendering just `<Provider>{children}</Provider>`, I'd have to make some checks on component types, but that could work, right?

Comment: Yes, the `onAuthenticatedMountCallback` should accept the type (enum) from the component

Comment: Well, that would only work for the first level of children though, wouldn't it?

```
<Provider>
  <Parent onAuthenticatedMountCallback={() => {}}>
    <Child onAuthenticatedMountCallback={???}>
  </Parent>
</Provider>

Comment: You have the `children`... You can traverse them while injecting a prop. This discussion starting to be out of the scope of the original question, I think I answered it, feel free to ask new focused questions.